# SF novel about no babies being born

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to remember the title of a novel I read years ago. It was set in England. The premise is that there are no babies being born anymore and no one in the world - as far as anyone knows - is pregnant. One of the main characters is pregnant, but no one believes her. She and her friends spend most of the novel avoiding the authorities, because they're afraid her baby will be taken away when people realize she really is pregnant. Sound familiar to anyone.

Comment: Sounds like the plot of Children of Men.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Children_of_Men - Was a novel.

Answer (score 17):

This is the novel [The Children of Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Children_of_Men) by P. D. James, on which the [similarly named 2006 film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_Men) was based.

> The Children of Men is a dystopian novel by P. D. James that was
> published in 1992. Set in England in 2021, it centres on the results
> of mass infertility. James describes a United Kingdom that is steadily
> depopulating and focuses on a small group of resisters who do not
> share the disillusionment of the masses.
>
> ...
>
> Soon after Theo's return, Miriam tells him that Gascoigne was arrested
> as he was trying to rig a Quietus landing stage to explode. The other
> Fishes are about to go on the run, and Julian wants him. Miriam
> reveals why Julian did not come herself—she is pregnant. Theo believes
> that Julian is deceiving herself, but when the two meet, Julian
> invites Theo to listen to her baby's heartbeat.

Comment: That sounds like it, so I just checked Amazon. That's the book. Thanks.